# Foreign key on composite primary key not working

Tags: php, zend-framework2, doctrine

I have an entity that references another entity with a composite primary key.

I'm simply doing a ManyToOne relationship.  Each company can have many trades.  Each company is part of some Stock Exchange and its unique identifier is both the Stock Exchange they're listed on and their stock symbol.

The error that I get when I try to update the schema is:

``` Column name ``id`` referenced for relation from Application\Entity\Trade towards Application\Entity\Company does not exist. ```

I think it's trying to default to `id` on the company.  Is there any way to specify multiple foreign keys for the primary key on one table?

```
<?php
namespace Application\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="trade")
 */
class Trade
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(name="id",type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $price;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $size;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $dateTime;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Company", inversedBy="trade")
     */
    protected $company;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $price
     */
    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getSize()
    {
        return $this->size;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $size
     */
    public function setSize($size)
    {
        $this->size = $size;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getDateTime()
    {
        return $this->dateTime;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $dateTime
     */
    public function setDateTime($dateTime)
    {
        $this->dateTime = $dateTime;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $id
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCompany()
    {
        return $this->company;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $company
     */
    public function setCompany($company)
    {
        $this->company = $company;
    }
}
```

Here's the company entity if that helps

```
<?php
namespace Application\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="company")
 */
class Company
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(length=5)
     */
    protected $symbol;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Application\Entity\Exchange", inversedBy="company")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="exchangeKey", referencedColumnName="exchangeKey")
     */
    protected $exchange;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getSymbol()
    {
        return $this->symbol;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $symbol
     */
    public function setSymbol($symbol)
    {
        $this->symbol = $symbol;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getExchange()
    {
        return $this->exchange;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $exchange
     */
    public function setExchange($exchange)
    {
        $this->exchange = $exchange;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reference multiple columns using the `@ORM\JoinColumns` annotation. Inside you can define one or more `@ORM\JoinColumn` annotations.

For example

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Company", inversedBy="trade")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="symbol", referencedColumnName="symbol"),
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="exchange", referencedColumnName="exchangeKey")
 * });
 */
protected $company;
```

I was going to link to the documentation, however all I can find is [this](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#joincolumns).

> An array of @JoinColumn annotations for a @ManyToOne or @OneToOne relation with an entity that has multiple identifiers.